# Need help in using REGEXP_REPLACE WITH LISTAGG function

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT
ID,
X.A_NO::INT AS A_NO,
REGEXP_REPLACE(TEXT_COL,'\::abcd::0|:::xyza::',' ') as TEXT_COL
FROM table X
WHERE date = '2022-02-02'
AND T_ID IN('12345','56789')
ORDER BY A_NO
)
SELECT
ID,
LISTAGG (distinct TEXT_COL , ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TEXT_COL) AS TEXT_COL_A
FROM CTE
GROUP BY ID;
```

When I run the above query, I'm getting results as mentioned below:

```
ID            TEXT_COL_A

12345       ,abc_xyz_ecom_data
56789
```

The value for TEXT_COL_A for the second row is empty. I want to remove the comma in the first row and update the second row AS NULL in the result. Can anyone guide me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second problem can be tackled with [IFNULL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/ifnull.html)

```
SELECT 'a' as a, IFNULL(a,'a was null') as b, null as c, IFNULL(c,'c was null') as d;
```

gives:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | a |  | c was null |

The first PROBLEM to remove things are the ends use [TRIM](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/trim.html), but to have just the start OR end trim use LTRIM or RTRIM

```
SELECT ',,a,,' as a, trim(a,','), ltrim(a,','), rtrim(a,',');
```

| A | TRIM(A,',') | LTRIM(A,',') | RTRIM(A,',') |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ,,a,, | a | a,, | ,,a |